# Customer GPS coordinates

Tags: sql, google-maps, gps, kml

We are a sales distribution company that serves more than 15,000 customer during the month. we have collected all  customer GEO coordinates using GPS device in my MS SQL server along with customer details (CustomerID,Name, visit day,visit sequence ..). I would like to import this information to Google map to draw and show each salesman territory and locate each customer in the map according to visit pattern that I have for each customer.

Please let me know the best possible way to do the same. This should be enable me to see all my customer in the map and filter them by visit day or by salesman.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Google Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/184641/)?  You could add a polygon layer to define the area for each salesman and use a different color marker for visit days (using the 'bucket' option in Fusion Tables Map Options).